# having issues with constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

```
SQL> Create Table Staff
  2  (StaffNo char(4) not null,
  3  FName char(15) not null,
  4  LName char(20) not null,
  5  Position char(10) not null,
  6  Sex char(1) check(value in('f','m')),
  7  Salary numeric(8,2),
  8  branchNO char(4) check(value in(select branchNo from branch)),
  9  Constraint StaffNopk primary key (StaffNo),
 10  constraint branchfk foreign key (branchNo) references branch (branchNo));
```

> Sex char(1) check(value in('f','m')),
> *
> ERROR at line 6:
> ORA-02438: Column check constraint cannot reference other columns

Can anyone please help me?

I am trying to create a table and encountered a problem as you can see in the statement s

Comment: The `CHAR` data-type is a fixed-length string. You probably do not want to use `CHAR` for names, which are variable-length, and would want `VARCHAR2` instead; if you use `CHAR` then your variable-length strings will be right-padded with white-space until they reach the correct length.

Answer (score 3):

Your immediate problem: `Sex char(1) check(value in('f','m')),` should be `Sex char(1) check(Sex in('f','m')),`. In your current attempt oracle thinks that `value` is a name of a column, and use of other columns in check constraints is prohibited.

Also, you don't need check for `branchNO`: foreign key will handle this check automatically.

```sql
Create Table Staff
(StaffNo char(4) not null,
 FName char(15) not null,
 LName char(20) not null,
 Position char(10) not null,
 Sex char(1) check(Sex in('f','m')),
 Salary numeric(8,2),
 branchNO char(4) not null,
 Constraint StaffNopk primary key (StaffNo),
 Constraint branchfk foreign key (branchNo) references branch (branchNo)
);
```

Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/OkVJ4H_l).